# What is the fastest way to input all of 30 million human "go" move into the computer that haven't digitized?

Tags: algorithms

What is the fastest way right now to input all of 30 million "go" move from the beginning into the computer that haven't digitized?

The idea is came from Google's AlphaGo

Comment: How is this a question about computer science and how is your tag "programming-languages" relevant?

Comment: How do you know there are 30 million "go" moves which have not been digitized?  Its a strange phrase since go moves are abstract concepts, not something which one digitizes.  Typically one digitizes records of previous games, such as those written on paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bottleneck when doing this will be to gather up all the not yet digitized moves, validate them somehow, and digitize them. Once that is done, reading in the data will be a snap.